# Does MASM have a :: operator?

Tags: assembly, masm

The Microsoft [operators reference for MASM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operators-reference) shows a `::` operator in the Miscellaneous section.

The link for this item opens the page for a [`;;` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/operator-semicolons).

I'm not whether this is a mistaken name in the table or a mistaken link on the item. There are several other items that do have mistaken links.

**Does MASM have a `::` operator?** What does it do?

Comment: [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/masm-numbers-and-operators#symbols_in_masm_expressions)'s a link for masm that mentions it.

Comment: Dramatically better material there than in the MASM docs proper @DavidWohlferd. Good one.

Comment: @DavidWohlferd That link is for Microsoft's Debugging Tools, and the use of the `::` operator to "indicate the members of a class" isn't supported by MASM itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it does.

I found a reference to it in an old [TASM 4 manual](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_assembler/Turbo_Assembler_4.1_for_OS2_Users_Guide_1994.pdf) (Page 124 of the printed document, 135 of the PDF).

It is used to define labels with a scope broader than the procedure they are defined in.

Consider:

```
foo PROC

lbl:
  ret

foo ENDP

bar PROC
 jmp lbl     ;Undefined symbol lbl
bar ENDP
```

This doesn't assemble in MASM because `lbl` is in another procedure.
However, this:

```
foo PROC

lbl::
  ret

foo ENDP

bar PROC
 jmp lbl     ;Fine
bar ENDP
```

does.

As far as I remember, labels in TASM/NASM behave differently, they don't have a scope (TASM can be made to emulate MASM though).

Comment: Thanks. Love reading your material BTW. Really satisfying how ordered you are.

Comment: In NASM, `lbl:` has file scope.  Local labels start with a `.` (so you'd write `.lbl:`), but they're really just syntactic sugar for `foo.lbl`.  So after `bar:`, you could still write `jmp foo.lbl`.  (NASM doesn't have any PROC stuff.  You just write `global foo` if you want the `foo` label to be exported in the symbol table.)

Comment: @PeterCordes That's why I love it! ;)

Answer (score 5):

The 1996 Microsoft book MASM Programmer's Guide 6.1 reveals some additional semantics.

A double colon `::` may be used to pass a far pointer produced from register values as an argument in a procedure call. Page 157 describes it:

> You can pass a **FAR** pointer in a *segment::offset* pair, as shown in the following. Note the use of double colons to separate the register pair.
>   ..
>   `INVOKE SomeProc, ES::BX, arg1, arg2`